# Include sources in fat JAR

Tags: gradle, jar, shadowjar

I use Gradle for a simple Java project and would like to produce a single fat JAR, which also contains the source code.

I prepared an example repository at: https://github.com/szarnyasg/gradle-shadowjar-source. I tried this `build.gradle` configuration:

```
plugins { id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "1.2.4" }

apply plugin: 'java'

shadowJar {
    classifier = 'fat'
    manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.example.MyMain' }
}

task packageSources(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts.archives packageSources
```

I can build this with:

```
./gradlew clean build shadowjar
```

This results in two JAR files in the `build/libs` directory:

- `example-fat.jar` - the fat JAR without sources
- `example.jar` - a JAR with (only) the sources

The documentation of the [Gradle Shadow plug-in](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) states that

> In the presence of the `java` or `groovy` plugins, Shadow will
>   automatically configure the following behavior:
>
> [...]
>
> - Configures the `shadowJar` task to include all sources from the
>     project’s main sourceSet.

For me, this implies that the source are included in the generated JAR, but this is probably not what it means.

It is possible to generate an executable fat JAR from Gradle, which also contains the source code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure how `shadowJar` handles sources but you can roll your own fat jar implementation.

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.jbirdvegas.so"

dependencies {
    // some dependencies to show the use case
    compile localGroovy(), 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21', 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jar {
    // set manifest
    manifest.attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Executable fat jar',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'com.jbirdvegas.q40744642.Hello'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    // baseName must be unique or it clashes with the default jar task output
    baseName = "$project.name-fat"
    // make sure you have a valid manifest
    manifest = jar.manifest
    // Here put the source output (class) files in the jar
    // as well as dependencies (jar) files.
    from sourceSets.main.output,
            configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}

// make sure our fatJar always runs immediately after the jar task
jar.finalizedBy fatJar
```

Now, after the jar task executes we have a ready to go executable jar

```
$ java -jar build/libs/q40744642-fat-0.1.jar 
[main] INFO com.jbirdvegas.q40744642.Hello - Hello World!
```

for completeness here is my `Hello.groovy` class

```
package com.jbirdvegas.q40744642

import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class Hello {
    static main(args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Hello.class)
        logger.info("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed the Groovy-related pieces and tried it on my repository with `gradle clean fatJar`, but the generated `example-fat-0.1.jar` does not contain any source code. I pushed the latest version to https://github.com/szarnyasg/gradle-shadowjar-source